# Combination of SQL Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following structure and i want to populate data to another table from this table with table structure table2

```
Table1

╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ State ║ City  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ A     ║ AA    ║
║ B     ║ BB    ║
║ C     ║ CC    ║
║ D     ║ DD    ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝

Table2 

╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ SrcState1 ║ SrcCity ║ DestState ║ DestCity  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A         ║ AA      ║ B         ║ BB        ║
║ A         ║ AA      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
║ A         ║ AA      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
║           ║         ║           ║           ║
║ B         ║ BB      ║ A         ║ AA        ║
║ B         ║ BB      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
║ B         ║ BB      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
║           ║         ║           ║           ║
║ C         ║ CC      ║ A         ║ AA        ║
║ C         ║ CC      ║ B         ║ BB        ║
║ C         ║ CC      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
║ D         ║ DD      ║ A         ║ AA        ║
║ D         ║ DD      ║ B         ║ BB        ║
║ D         ║ DD      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

**EDIT**
**Actually it should look like this:**

```
    ╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
    ║ SrcState1 ║ SrcCity ║ DestState ║ DestCity  ║
    ╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
    ║ A         ║ AA      ║ B         ║ BB        ║
    ║ A         ║ AA      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
    ║ A         ║ AA      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
    ║           ║         ║           ║           ║
    ║ B         ║ BB      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
    ║ B         ║ BB      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
    ║           ║         ║           ║           ║
    ║ C         ║ CC      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
    ╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS JOIN to generate Cartesian Product `tab x tab` and exclude in `WHERE tab.state <> tab.state`:

This solution works for original question.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2434/5/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tab(state NVARCHAR(10), City NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO tab(state, city)
VALUES ('A', 'AA'), ('B', 'BB'), ('C', 'CC'), ('D', 'DD');

SELECT 
   a.state
   ,a.city
   ,b.state
   ,b.city
FROM tab a
CROSS JOIN tab b
WHERE a.state <> b.state
ORDER BY  a.state, a.city, b.state, b.city
```

For future state your question clearly if you want to get something like below use [shA.t Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32285882/5070879):

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ SrcState1 ║ SrcCity ║ DestState ║ DestCity  ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A         ║ AA      ║ B         ║ BB        ║
║ A         ║ AA      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
║ A         ║ AA      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
║           ║         ║           ║           ║
║ B         ║ BB      ║ C         ║ CC        ║
║ B         ║ BB      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
║           ║         ║           ║           ║
║ C         ║ CC      ║ D         ║ DD        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: How to remove duplicates

A  AA   B  BB
B  BB   A  AA

Comment: @Balaji Don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Balaji Still don't undestand, look at link to fiddle. There is no duplicates

Comment: How to remove duplicates

 
  <table>  <tr><td>SrcState1 </td><td>SrcCity</td><td>DestState </td><td>DestCity</td> </tr>
<tr> <td> A</td> <td>AA</td><td>B</td> <td>BB</td></tr>
<tr> <td> B</td> <td>BB</td><td>A</td> <td>AA</td></tr>
</table>
I Need one rows and remove duplicate row. both row given same result

Comment: @Balaji Result is exactly as in your question.

Comment: @Balaji Rows `A AA B BB` is different from `B BB A AA`, there are no duplicates

Comment: my exact result


<table>
<tr> <td>state1</td> <td>city1</td> <td>state2</td> <td>city2</td></tr>
<tr> <td> A </td> <td> AA </td> <td> B </td> <td> BB </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> A </td> <td> AA </td> <td> C </td> <td> CC </td> </tr>
<tr> <td> A </td> <td> AA </td> <td> D </td> <td> DD </td> </tr>


<tr> <tdB </td> <td> BB </td> <td>C </td> <td> CC </td> </tr>
<tr> <td>B </td> <td> BB </td> <td> D  </td> <td> DD </td> </tr>

<tr> <td> C </td> <td> CC </td> <td> D </td> <td> DD </td> </tr>

</table>

Comment: @Balaji I really don't understand what you want to achieve, look at your question, look at fiddle and compare.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN
    Table1 t2 ON t1.[state] < t2.[state];
```

or for a better solution:

```
;WITH t AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [State]) As rn
    FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM t t1
    INNER JOIN
    t t2 ON t1.rn < t2.rn;
```

Comment: Now I get it, but OP could state it in question clearly, reading html from comment isn't easy